# Adding multiple WMS layers with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is it possible to add multiple/all layers from a WMS service with PyQGIS?

It is possible to add a WMS layer with PyQGIS if layer name to be added is exactly known. (which is 'MA-ALUS' in the code below)

```
urlWithParams = 'url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=MA-ALUS&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301' 
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MA-ALUS', 'wms') 
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Assuming that if want to add all of the layers in the WMS service, what should be the proper PyQGIS code/implementation?

e.g. code below gives a list of all layers in the WMS if it is executed under QGIS Python Console (so that one can choose and add multiple layers).

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("https://tucbs-public-api.csb.gov.tr/csb_cdp_abi_wms?&service=wms")
```

My question is; **is it possible to implement similar operation with PyQGIS?**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this, is to set the layername=0. In most cases even in both of your examples it works.

Try `url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=0&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301`

Comment: Already tried that but it does not work. WMS URL **https://gis-prod-api.csb.gov.tr/orman_wms** has many layers in. Service works. You can add desired layer via PyQGIS by specifying desired layer name e.g. layer "18". But if you try to add layer "0" you get following message "Oop! test_wms cannot be loaded. Either the server is down or you have limited internet connectivity" Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test this, wms doesn't work for me, because server was not found.

Answer (score 0):

The post is old but I have the answer :

In your exemple :

```
url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=MA-ALUS&layers=[SECOND-LAYER]&layers=[THIRD-LAYER]&styles=&styles=&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301
```

You must have same number of "layers" and "styles" attributes.